# Fitting discreet distribution to data

Tags: python

I have come across [fitter package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fitter) in python which fits the continuous distributions to the given data and identifies the most closest distribution which fits the data

Now if I want to check for the discreet distribution , as in which discreet distributions fits the data best for and example

If my data contains just array of values

```
A = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
```

I want to check if my data fits with binomial/Poisson/or any other discrete distributions.

I have gone through few statistical approaches:
Ks test is being used but it is only for continuous data.

On exploring I got to know python has chisquare test which takes actual value and expected values and degree of freedom as input.
If I just have actual values and not expected values then is it a correct way to validate of my data fits to discrete distributions.

Can someone help me understand which statistical test would be ideal for this scenario?

Comment: Can someone suggest any options

Comment: Your data is continuous rather than discrete. Are you trying to fit a continuous distribution into a discrete one?